# A field was longer or shorter than the server allows - Rails production environment error

Tags: paypal, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemerchant

I am using paypal direct payment in rails application. I am integrated in live site, while purchasing the any item its showing error like,

> A field was longer or shorter than the server allows

```
require 'rubygems'
            require 'active_merchant'
            ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production
            credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
            :number     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            :month      => '3',
            :year       => '2018',
            :first_name => 'xxxxxx',
            :last_name  => 'xxxxxxx',
            :verification_value  => 'xxxxxx'
            )
            gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
            :login => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            :password => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            :signature => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "
            )   
            response = gateway.authorize(1, credit_card, :ip => '127.1.1.1')
```

please give solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only errors that are showing on your account is the following.

errorcode  10501
shortmessage  "Invalid Configuration"
longmessage  "This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration."

This can be caused when you try to perform a DoDirectPayment API request and do not have Pro enabled on your account.  It's possible that your software is translating that error into the field error that you are seeing.  Please reach out to customer support if you wish to enable Pro on your account to be able to perform DoDirectPayment API calls.

Comment: any other solution? How to enable to Pro?

Comment: For live accounts you would need to contact PayPal customer support, for sandbox accounts typically you can enable this on the accounts yourself and for the ones that have issues MTS can usually enable these.